# Updating more than one data with the same id from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

my tables are like this

```
maklumatakaun    |   detailakaun
----------------------------------
id(A.I)          |     idDetail(A.I)
NoAkaun          |     KodLokasi
KodBahagian      |     NoTelefon
KodKategori      |     KodJenisAkaun
KodKategori      |     id
Tarif            |
```

I'm trying to update my data inside two tables at once (maklumatakaun , detailakaun) in detailakaun there are  column 'KodLokasi' 'KodJenisAkaun' and 'NoTelefon' that could have more than one data entry under one id. Here's what i got so far

extract ($_POST);

if ($_POST) {

```
$NoAkaun            = isset($_POST['NoAkaun'])          ? $_POST['NoAkaun'] : '';
$KodBahagian        = isset($_POST['KodBahagian'])      ? $_POST['KodBahagian'] : '';
$Tarif              = isset($_POST['Tarif'])            ? $_POST['Tarif'] : '';
$KodDaerah          = isset($_POST['KodDaerah'])        ? $_POST['KodDaerah'] : '';
$KodKategori        = isset($_POST['KodKategori'])      ? $_POST['KodKategori'] : '';
$NoTelefon          = isset($_POST['NoTelefon'])        ? $_POST['NoTelefon'] : '';
$KodLokasi          = isset($_POST['KodLokasi'])        ? $_POST['KodLokasi'] : '';
$KodJenisAkaun      = isset($_POST['KodJenisAkaun'])    ? $_POST['KodJenisAkaun'] : '';
$akaun_id           = isset($_POST['akaun_id'])         ? $_POST['akaun_id'] : '';






$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE maklumatakaun
                    SET NoAkaun = '$NoAkaun' , 
                    KodBahagian = '$KodBahagian' , 
                    KodDaerah = '$KodDaerah' , 
                    KodKategori = '$KodKategori' , 
                    Tarif = '$Tarif' , 
                    WHERE id = '$id'");
$akaun_id = mysql_insert_id();
foreach ($NoTelefon AS $i => $telefon){
$sql= mysql_query ("UPDATE detailakaun
                    SET KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun[$i]' ,  
                    KodLokasi = '$KodLokasi[$i]' , 
                    NoTelefon = '$telefon'
                    ");
```

This code would update all the columns inside the two table but lets say one account have was registered with 3 'KodLokasi' , 'KodJenisAkaun', and 'NoTelefon' then when updated with only one of the 3 columns it will repeat itself to 3. How can i update this properly?

Comment: Seems like you need a WHERE clause on the second update statement. Identify *which* rows you want to update. This code is open to SQL Injection. It's 2015 already why are we giving examples using the mysql interface that's been deprecated for how many years? The mysqli and PDO interfaces both provide support for prepared statements. I'm clueless as to why there's a call to `mysql_insert_id` function following an `UPDATE` query. Why the plastic is that there? The return from that is only valid immediately following an INSERT that successfully inserts a row with a col assigned by AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

How to update it properly?

Use **mysqli** or **PDO** rather than the deprecated mysql interface.

Don't overwrite the value of a variable from the post with a nonsensical call to a function that isn't valid where it's called.

Use a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement to identify *which* rows you need to update. Or if the two tables are related by some set of columns, use a join operation to identify the rows.

And for the love all things that are good and beautiful in this world... STOP writing code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Just STOP. Use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**. And if you stuck with an interface that doesn't support prepared statements, then properly escape the unsafe values included in SQL text.

That's how to update it properly.